# Does installing multiple desktop environments affect performance?

Tags: gnome, openbox

I love having multiple DEs on my linux laptop... I currently have Unity, Gnome3, gnome classic and Openbox. Would this mean slower performances?
Thanks a bunch!

Alex

Comment: Gnome 2 and Gnome 3 would be a bit problematic. Gnome 3 and MATE (fork of Gnome 2) should work though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, installing and keeping different DE's does not mean slower performance. But when you are on a DE, you can try to avoid using an application which loads the other DE's modules, libraries etc.

Answer (score 0):

Using multiple DE might affect the stability of the OS because some of the DE come with its own dependencies. I use unity, Gnome, gnome classic, gnome metacity, gnome compiz and cairo dock but on start up i choose a specific environment i want to use and use it rather than mixing them up.