# How can I know if my an application on my desktop environment is loading other DE's modules, libraries, etc?

Tags: desktop-environments, libraries, modules

I read [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/78499/54934) and it's [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/78504/54934) about multiple desktop environments and how they might impact system performance and was wondering:

How do I know if I'm using an "application which loads the other DE's modules, libraries etc"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general way , you can actually lookup in [**Synaptic manager**](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/precise/synaptic/) by selecting the `SECTIONS` menu, having **GNOME** Desktop , **KDE** desktop , amd **XFCE** desktop environment sub-sections, stating the default applications either **QT** or **GTK** based.

And ,there is **Library** section , a shared section showing Libraries of **Gnome** and **Kde** desktop . If you can take a look in description of some of them ,you will find **similarity** in some of QT's with GTK's ,  etc.

**Gnome** and **KDE** don't have shared Libraries but some common modules like **KERNEL** and drivers , but different frontends like network managers , sound menu ,etc for them  based on DE's .

**Dependencies** of DE based applications are explained nicely in the [above reverendj1's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/160039/63025). Apart from that you can use utilities like [apt-cache](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man8/apt-cache.8.html) ,[dpkg](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/dpkg.1.html) ,[dpkg-query](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/dpkg-query.1.html) to get detailed package information and its dependencies and runtime libraries.

And pointing to multiple Desktops modules or library's usage , in simple words if you have **KDE** and **GNOME** installed , on running  **KDE application in Gnome environment will  initialize KDE library and vice-versa** to polish its interface  , integration ,etc . So you will be having two different **Core Library** functions running. If you have considerable memory for both of them , then its quite a fun to try.

---

There are  commands like

> [**ldd**](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/ldd.1.html)
>   -->>
>
> which prints  the  shared  libraries  required by each program or
>   shared library specified on the command line.

For example

```
ldd -u /usr/bin/nautilus
Unused direct dependencies:
    linux-vdso.so.1
    /usr/lib/libzeitgeist-1.0.so.1
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgailutil-3.so.0
    /usr/lib/libgnome-desktop-3.so.2
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libX11.so.6
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgmodule-2.0.so.0
    /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnotify.so.4
......
```

> [ltrace](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/precise/en/man1/ltrace.1.html)
>   -->>
>
> ```
> ltrace  is  a  program  that simply runs the specified command until it
>        exits.  It intercepts and records the dynamic library calls  which  are
>        called  by  the  executed process and the signals which are received by
>        that process.  It  can  also  intercept  and  print  the  system  calls
>        executed by the program.
> ```

For example

```
ltrace  ping
__libc_start_main(0x4014a0, 1, 0x7fffdbad54a8, 0x405b00, 0x405b90 <unfinished ...>
socket(2, 3, 1)                                                                                        = 3
__errno_location()                                                                                     = 0x7f0ed1c7a6a0
getuid()                                                                                               = 0
setuid(0)                                                                                              = 0
getopt(1, 0x7fffdbad54a8, "h?VQ:I:M:aUc:dfi:w:l:S:np:qrs:vL"...)                                       = -1
fwrite("Usage: ping [-LRUbdfnqrvVaAD] [-"..., 1, 251, 0x7f0ed1a6d180Usage: ping [-LRUbdfnqrvVaAD] [-c count] [-i interval] [-w deadline]
            [-p pattern] [-s packetsize] [-t ttl] [-I interface]
            [-M pmtudisc-hint] [-m mark] [-S sndbuf]
            [-T tstamp-options] [-Q tos] [hop1 ...] destination
)                                  = 251
exit(2 <unfinished ...>
+++ exited (status 2) +++
```

Answer (score 2):

When installing programs, you can look at their requirements. I don't think you can show this in Ubuntu Software Center, but when you install programs with the terminal, using `apt-get`, it will show you the requirements it is installing and ask if it is ok. If they include another DE, don't install them.

Most KDE applications either start with K, or have an emphasized K in their name (i.e. Amarok, Koffice, etc). I don't THINK the other DEs are really necessary to steer away from, as I THINK they mostly use GTK, which is what Gnome uses.

To see if anything has installed KDE, simply open a terminal, and use the following command:

```
sudo apt-get remove kde-runtime
```

If it errors out and says `Package kde-runtime-data is not installed, so not removed`, you're good. Nothing to worry about. If instead, it shows a bunch of programs that are installed and no longer required, then look at the part where it says `The following packages will be REMOVED`. These are the programs you will have to replace (if you know what they are and you installed them). Jot those down, and proceed with the uninstall.

If you do need to uninstall kde-runtime, make sure to run `sudo apt-get autoremove` afterwords, which will clean up all the other unnecessary cruft installed alongside KDE.

After saying all of this, the performance hit when running programs from different DE's is blown out of proportion on modern computers. I always use Gnome, but I install KDE programs with reckless abandon when they are better than their Gnome counterparts, and have never really noticed much of a difference.

Answer (score 0):

I aint 100 percent if this what you asking but I had Gnome unity and kde installed a while ago they did not seem to affect system performance but I did have 2 sets of aplications one for gnome {unity is gnome} and one for KDE but most applications were obviously named like Gedit Gparted etc for gnome and Kate or Konquour for kde.

But you can get the desktops with out all the apps but geanraly gnome and kde would not even execute each others programs very well but it was a pain to have all those apps any way so I just use unity now

hope this is usefull...