# Which programming-model does Ubuntu follow?

Tags: development, source-code

I am curious to know which programming model does the ubuntu follows in its own  development process; does it follow the object-oriented programming model (and use languages like python, java etc ) or does it follows the traditional procedural programming model (languages like C, ASM).

Answer (score 4):

**In general, there is no stipulated language or programming model for Ubuntu.**

---

In Ubuntu, you can use just about any programming language to create your application(s), so long as the language is supported via any bindings and libraries that it requires.

For example, you can write application for Ubuntu that target either [GTK+](http://www.gtk.org/) or [Qt](http://qt.nokia.com/), which both support several languages (C++, Python, Java, etc). GTK+ specifically is written in C, but many applications which target GTK+ use Python.

*Other (non-default) targets (GUI related I mean), include [EFL](http://www.enlightenment.org/p.php?p=about/efl) (Enlightenment Foundation Libraries) and Tk. Both of these have bindings in various languages.*

---

So, in a nutshell, it really doesn't matter what you use, or which programming model (Object-Oriented, Procedural, etc) you prefer. Ubuntu is open to any of them.

---

For more you can see this site: http://developer.ubuntu.com - which will give you tutorials and other relevant information.

Comment: @rolland, sir i want to know in which language is Ubuntu itself is written; which could help me find out the programming-model Ubuntu follow itself.

Comment: @Ankit - I would advise you to  take a look at this [answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/162126/63025) if you want to know Ubuntu's Core fundamentals briefly.  .Just to add , it follows the model , the developer thinks or feels is essential for its working. Since it is Open-Source which means having freedom to improve as you like.

Comment: @Ankit Ubuntu is a Linux ***distribution***. It is not "written in a language", it is made up several programs written in many different languages. P.S. your original question and your comment are worlds apart in what you intend to know :).